# In Android, using OSRMRoadManager how to get route by foot method?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using OSRMRoadManager in osmdroid bonus pack to obtain a route between two points.
I am wondering if there is an option to specify the route should be by foot method? It seems the method is by car.

```
RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(this);
ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(destLocation.getLatitude(), destLocation.getLongitude());
waypoints.add(startPoint);
waypoints.add(endPoint);
asyncTask = new UpdateRoadTask(this, map);
asyncTask.execute(waypoints);

public class UpdateRoadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Road> {

private Context mContext;
private MapView mMap;

public UpdateRoadTask (Context context, MapView map){
    mContext = context;
    mMap = map;
}

protected Road doInBackground(Object... params) {
   // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = (ArrayList<GeoPoint>)params[0];
    RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(mContext);


    return roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Road result) {
    Road road = result;
    
    if(road.mStatus != Road.STATUS_OK)
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error when loading the road - status="+road.mStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);

    mMap.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
    mMap.invalidate();
   
}
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1) mentions a `setMean()` method to set the mode of transport and gives the example `((OSRMRoadManager)roadManager).setMean(OSRMRoadManager.MEAN_BY_BIKE);`. Maybe there's support for walking as well(?) Looks like there's `MEAN_BY_FOOT` too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some reason, the setMean method is not recognized for OSRMRoadManager and neither is OSRMRoadManager.MEAN_BY_BIKE.

Comment: Solved it by updating osmdroid bonus pack to the most recent version.